# Query where column value contains specific word

Tags: mysqli

I am doing a query using `LIKE` to pull results that contain a specific name:

```
SELECT ID FROM accessories WHERE ItemName LIKE '%stripe%'
```

The only problem is that I'm getting results which include the word "stripe" as well as "stripes", "striped", etc.

How can I modify this query to pull only results where an individual word equals exactly "stripe"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT ID FROM accessories WHERE ItemName LIKE '%stripe %'
```

or

```
SELECT ID FROM accessories WHERE ItemName LIKE '%stripe%' and ItemName NOT LIKE '%stripes%'
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was simple enough. I will accept the answer as soon as I'm able. (I used your first example)